# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE error in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I wrote a simple mysql procedure as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
create procedure trialdbjs.spDeleteEmployees(in IDs nvarchar(1000))
Begin
    Delete from employees_js Where ID IN (IDs);
end$$
```

it works for single values of IDs but when I call the procedure with a comma separated value such as: '2,4'

for example: 
call trialdbjs.spDeleteEmployees('2,4');

This returns an error of: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2,4'

I hope you can help me!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write the stored procedure this way.  The problem is `IN`.  It is treating `'2,4'` as a string value and then trying to convert it to a number (because `id` is a number).

Here is one way to solve this:

```
delimiter $$ 
create procedure trialdbjs.spDeleteEmployees(
    in in_IDs nvarchar(1000)
)
Begin
    Delete from employees_js Where find_in_set(id, in_IDs) > 0;
end$$
```

There are other ways to solve this problem (dynamic SQL would be faster because it can make use of an index).